# Jmeter- Load testing EC2 instance, only 50% request are successful

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, jmeter

I am trying to load test Nginx installed on an EC2 instance via Jmeter, Everytime I try to load test, only 50% request are successful,

```
For Eg:

If I try with 10 users, only 5 response are OK
If I try with 100 users, only 50 response are OK
If I try with 500, only 250 response are OK
```

Any Idea, regarding this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds weird. I would recommend the following troubleshooting techniques:

1. First of all always check *jmeter.log* file, it should contain enough information to get to the bottom of your test failure(s).
2. If JMeter log file doesn't contain any suspicious entries next step would be checking response messages using i.e. [View Results In Table](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) and/or [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. This should provide you some high-level information and trends, i.e. you will be able to see if some particular sampler(s) is(are) always failing.
3. If above steps don't give enough clue to resolve your issue you can temporary enable saving of request and response data to see what is wrong with the failing sampler(s). Add the next lines to *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
   jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
   ```

   and next time your run JMeter test the .jtl results file will contain all the relevant data which can be analyzed using aforementioned [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. Don't forget to revert the change once you fix the script as [JMeter listeners are very resource intensive](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) per se and above settings greatly increase disk IO and it may ruin your test.
4. If none of above helps - check logs on the application under test side, most probably you will get something from them.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, What I found was that when I migrated app to another cloud provider, it worked, so it might be flaky connection of cloud provider.

Comment: Or, you misconfigured DNS, so you were actually testing against two different servers, one of which didn't exist, or you had a load balancer that wasn't configured correctly.